# Accessing current user on ExpressJs - Passport

Tags: express, passport.js

I'm creating a backend app using expressJs and passportjs (local strategy) to secure some of the routes.
I need to add the information for the current user on every Database query so we only expose the relevant information to each user.
I know you can access the information for current user checking req.user, but that will involve passing the user information (or even the request) as a parameter through all my call-stack, and I found it a bit inconvenient.

Is there to get the user information on the last layer (the one preparing the sql statement) without adding it on the parameters?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not get the user information on the last layer by `id` ? Since you are using passport-local, you can query a user by id in the last database query by accessing `req.user.id` . No parameter is needed.

```
 router.post('/your/route', function(req, res) {
   User.findOne({
     where: {id: req.user.id}
   }).then(function(user) {
   // do something
    });
 //send response
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That way I still need to pass in the userId to query the DB. I'm trying to avoid adding extra parameters to all methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass to passport's `done` function as the second parameter the user object with your custom data, like this:

```
done(null, {id: 1, name: 'John'});
```

and the `req.user` will return `{id: 1, name: 'John'}`